# Python. Как на локальном сервере сделать определенный адрес?

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-сервер

У меня есть локальный сервер на Python:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        message = "Server working!"

        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
        return



server = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8081), myHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо 127.0.0.1:8081 выводилось example.local без внесения изменений в файл hosts?

Comment: Никак  Можно конечно поднять свой собственный DNS сервер, но вряд ли это норм вариант, если даже модификация hosts не рассматривается.

Answer (score 0):

В файле host присвоить локальному адресу имя. Вроде так.
так как ето локальний сайт, то можно ето сделать следуючим образом : Windows->system32->drivers->etc-> далее открываеш файл hosts, и далле прописуеш 
10.10.10.34 asdfasf

1